# Is Kendo UI Dataviz chart supported in IE8?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dataviz

When I run the Kendo Chart in IE9, everything works fine. But in IE8, the design is not as good as in IE9. Means X-axis and Y-axis value is not displayed properly in IE8.

Thanks...

Comment: Why not ask Telerik in their support forum?

Answer (score 1):

IE can be very sensitive to the options that map to CSS attributes. For example, font settings must be with valid CSS syntax, otherwise the rendering is aborted.
Please try to exclude any non-essential options from the chart configuration to see if that helps.Please refer this link for further [Information](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-dataviz/chart/more-ie8-issues.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience all chart's basic functionality works properly in IE8. However, to get the width right, sometimes you'll need to set the width when initialising the chart using `HtmlAttributes`.

Example:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<MyModel>()
    .Name("chart")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { Style = "width:400px;" })
    .Etc...
)
```

**What Telerik says:**

[Supported Browsers](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/supported-browsers#fully-supported-browsers)

```
Browser             Supported versions
Internet Explorer   9 and later
Chrome              21 and later
Firefox             24 and later, ESR
Opera               15 and later
OS X Safari         5 and later
iOS Safari          4 and later
Chrome for Mobile   4 and later
```

[Browsers with limited support](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/supported-browsers#browsers-with-limited-support)

- Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8 are supported with the following
  limitations:

  - PDF export is not supported.
  - Image export is not supported.
  - 64-bit versions do not support text rotation.
  - Pie and donut charts don't have gradients
- Internet Explorer 10 does not support dashed lines in canvas. This affects the exportImage as well.
- Android 2.x will use non-interactive canvas output